# How to render a single mathjax equation?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am working on a webpage that MathJax doesn't play well with.  There are `display:none` nodes, latex text nested into svgs, and all manner of other unpleasantness.  Instead of having MathJax automatically attempt to parse through my site looking for $$ and figuring out the size of text, and all of the other magic, it would be way easier if I could just call an API with the appropriate size parameters and the equation text and get back an svg that I will embed with my own two hands.  Is this possible?

I have found [this page](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/test/sample-dynamic-2.html) which does dynamic rendering, but it seems to parse the entire page to accomplish this behavior.  I would like to just render a single equation.

Answer (score 1):

[Codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) provides a nice editor for testing out formulas, and it makes it easy to embed nice equations in your page. At the bottom of the page, there's a place to copy code to embed. The urls tend to use `/gif.latex`, but turns out you can swap `gif` for `svg`.

A call to `https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?` followed by the latex for your equation will return the image.

```
<img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.latex?a^b&plus;b^2=c^2"/>
```

[image]